# How to study if an alternating series with squareroot n minus n is absolute convergent or simply convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

So, I am supposed to tell if the following series is absolute convergent or simply convergent:
$$\sum(-1)^n\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)$$

To study ther absolute convergence I know that I need to study the convergence of the following series:
$$\sum \left| (-1)^n\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right) \right|= \sum\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)$$

But I'm stuck on how to study such series.

Also, if it's not absolute convergent, how do I study the convergence of the alternating series?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your series is the same as $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+1} $. So it is an alternating series with terms $\to 0$. So it is converging. It is not absolutely converging: compare with $\sum 1/n$.

Comment: @markvs Should be $\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n$, not $\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + 1$ in the denominator.

Comment: OK. It does not change the rest.

Comment: why is it the same as $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$ ?

Comment: because $\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n\right)=n^2+1-n^2=1$ so $(-1)^n\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)=\frac{(-1)^n\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n\right)}{\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n\right)} =\frac{(-1)^n}{\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n\right)}$

Comment: Oh, we multiply by the conjugate.

Comment: by the way, $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} \sim \frac{1}{n}$ right?

Comment: There’s no way $$\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\sim \frac1n,$$ since the left side does not depend on $n.$ @msmilkshake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We study the absolute convergence. We know that: $$\sqrt{1+n^2}-n=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-n\right)=n\cdot \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-1\right)\sim n\cdot \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\,\,\, n\to +\infty$$
So, the series is not absolutely convergent by the asymptotic criteria and by comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ that diverges.

The series is convergent pointwise. Namely, $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ is decreasing, infinitesimal because:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt{n^2+1}-n=0$$
And always non-negative because $n^2+1>n^2\,\, \forall n$.

So, the seriesis pointwise convergent by the Leibniz criteria.